# How to display .tif image in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

This code is working for .png images.

```
   getNextImage(imageObj:{imageName:string,cityImageId:number,imgNumber:number}):void{
    this.imgNumber= imageObj.imgNumber;
    this.imagePath=`assets/images/${imageObj.imageName}.png`;
    this.cityImageId=imageObj.cityImageId;
   }
```

But when using images of .tif format, then image is not loading it is just showing blank

```
 getNextImage(imageObj:{imageName:string,cityImageId:number,imgNumber:number}):void{
        this.imgNumber= imageObj.imgNumber;
        this.imagePath=`assets/images/${imageObj.imageName}.tif`;
        this.cityImageId=imageObj.cityImageId;
       }
```

What to do to make it work normally for tif format images also?

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to the browser support, and as of now (12/27/21) only Safari supports the TIFF images.

As recommended by MDN, it's best to avoid such file extensions, and go for the images that are supported widely by the community (eg. png,jpg,jpeg etc), so you should probably convert them to `png|jpg|jpeg` to get the ball rolling.

More details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types